# TypeScript error while accessing Proxy Object | Object[] in MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a simple MobX Store:

```
import { observable, action, makeObservable } from "mobx"
import { BoxShadow, ShadowValues } from "./types"
import { boxShadow } from "./constants"

interface IStore {
    shadow: BoxShadow
}

export class Store implements IStore {
    shadow: BoxShadow = {
        selected: "DEFAULT",
        list: boxShadow,
    }
    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            shadow: observable,
            updateShadow: action.bound,
        })
    }

    updateShadow(selected: ShadowValues) {
        this.shadow.selected = selected
    }
}

export const store = new Store()
```

The `BoxShadow` & `ShadowValues` type consists of:

```
type Point = {
    x: number
    y: number
}

export type ShadowValues =
    | "none"
    | "sm"
    | "DEFAULT"
    | "md"
    | "lg"
    | "xl"
    | "2xl"
    | "3xl"

export type Shadow = {
    offset: Point
    blur: number
    shadow: number
    color: string
}

export type ShadowList = Record<ShadowValues, Shadow[] | Shadow>

export type BoxShadow = {
    selected: ShadowValues
    list: ShadowList
}
```

I am using HTML select & updating the `boxShadow` values:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { toJS } from "mobx"
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

import { useStore } from "./context"
import { Select } from "./Select"
import { shadows } from "./constants"

import { ShadowValues } from "./types"

export default observer(function App() {
    const { shadow, updateShadow } = useStore()

    console.log(toJS(shadow.list[shadow.selected])[0]["offset"])
    console.log(shadow.list[shadow.selected].offset)

    return (
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center">
            <h1 className="text-4xl">Access MobX Proxy</h1>
            <Select
                className="flex-1 w-56"
                label="Box Shadow"
                checkmark={true}
                options={shadows}
                selectedOption={
                    shadows.filter(({ value }) => value === shadow.selected)[0]
                }
                onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                    const selected = selectedOption.value as ShadowValues
                    updateShadow(selected)
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
})
```

However, I'm unable to access `selectedShadow.color` or `selectedShadow.offset` without TypeScript yelling at me.

The `boxShadow` values consists of an object or an array of objects like:

```
export const boxShadow = {
    none: {
        offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        blur: 0,
        shadow: 0,
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
    },
    sm: {
        offset: { x: 0, y: 1 },
        blur: 2,
        shadow: 0,
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
    },
    DEFAULT: [
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 1 },
            blur: 3,
            shadow: 0,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
        },
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 1 },
            blur: 2,
            shadow: 0,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
        },
    ],
    md: [
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 4 },
            blur: 6,
            shadow: -1,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
        },
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 2 },
            blur: 4,
            shadow: -1,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
        },
    ],
    lg: [
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 10 },
            blur: 15,
            shadow: -3,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
        },
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 4 },
            blur: 6,
            shadow: -2,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
        },
    ],
    xl: [
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 20 },
            blur: 25,
            shadow: -5,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
        },
        {
            offset: { x: 0, y: 10 },
            blur: 10,
            shadow: -5,
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)",
        },
    ],
    "2xl": {
        offset: { x: 0, y: 25 },
        blur: 50,
        shadow: -12,
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    },
    "3xl": {
        offset: { x: 0, y: 35 },
        blur: 60,
        shadow: -15,
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
    },
}
```

I am trying to access it using `toJS` but still can't access nested properties. The `.toJS` method however displays perfectly fine if I `console.log` it:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { toJS } from "mobx"
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

import { useStore } from "./context"
import { Select } from "./Select"
import { shadows } from "./constants"

import { ShadowValues } from "./types"

export default observer(function App() {
    const { shadow, updateShadow } = useStore()

    console.log(toJS(shadow.list[shadow.selected])[0]["offset"])
    console.log(shadow.list[shadow.selected].offset)

    return (
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center">
            <h1 className="text-4xl">Access MobX Proxy</h1>
            <Select
                className="flex-1 w-56"
                label="Box Shadow"
                checkmark={true}
                options={shadows}
                selectedOption={
                    shadows.filter(({ value }) => value === shadow.selected)[0]
                }
                onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                    const selected = selectedOption.value as ShadowValues
                    updateShadow(selected)
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
})
```

Check out the `console.log` above. I want to access those values somehow.

If I do `shadow.list[shadow.selected][0].color`, I get:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'string | Shadow[] | Shadow'.
> Property '0' does not exist on type 'string | Shadow[] | Shadow'.

And if I do `shadow.list[shadow.selected].color`, I get:

> TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'string | Shadow[] | Shadow'.
> Property 'color' does not exist on type 'string'.

Which is correct but I don't know how to solve it :(

I have made [a minimal Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/listbox-headlessui-react-tailwind-mobx-access-proxy-p1j6r) to see the demo. Note that it sometimes `console.log`'s on Codesandbox but doesn't locally but it does give TS errors on Codesandbox too.

How can I solve the issue? I want to access the object value `sm.offset` plus the array of objects too `DEFAULT[0].offset` & `DEFAULT[1].offset` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have the type as `Shadow | Shadow[]`, I had to add a guard to narrow the type when I had to access it. So I did the following to make it work:

```
if (Array.isArray(selected)) {
    console.log(selected[0].offset);
} else {
    console.log(selected.offset);
}
```

I tried `typeof selected` & it was giving me `object` all the time & I forgot that JS considers everything an `object` so never tried the above stuff :)